# Copy directory conents from Az datalakegen2 to different storage account using CLI

Tags: azure, azure-powershell, azure-data-lake-gen2

I'm looking for a way to copy directory contents to a directory on a different storage account. Both of the storage accounts are Azure Data Lake Storage Gen2. I would like to achieve this using the CLI.

For example I have files in storageaccount1: datalake/directory/*.parquet and I want to copy them to storageaccount2: some/path/

I've tried to accomplish this using AzCopy, but I can't get it to work.

```
AzCopy copy "https://storageaccount1.blob.core.windows.net/raw/2023/02/10/*" "https://storageaccount2.blob.core.windows.net/test"
```

Reponse

```
    INFO: Login succeeded.
PS C:...> 
INFO: Scanning...
INFO: Autologin not specified.
INFO: Authenticating to destination using Azure AD
INFO: Authenticating to source using Azure AD
INFO: Failed to create one or more destination container(s). Your transfers may still succeed if the container already exists.
INFO: Any empty folders will not be processed, because source and/or destination doesn't have full folder support

failed to perform copy command due to error: cannot start job due to error: cannot list files due to reason -> github.com/Azure/azure-storage-blob-go/azblob.newStorageError, /home/vsts/go/pkg/mod/github.com/!azure/azure-storage-blob-go@v0.15.0/azblob/zc_storage_error.go:42
===== RESPONSE ERROR (ServiceCode=InvalidResourceName) =====
Description=The specifed resource name contains invalid characters.
RequestId:xxxxxx
Time:2023-02-10T15:40:31.1266189Z, Details:
   Code: InvalidResourceName
   GET https://x.blob.core.windows.net/xxxxx
   Authorization: REDACTED
   User-Agent: [AzCopy/10.17.0 Azure-Storage/0.15 (go1.19.2; Windows_NT)]
   X-Ms-Client-Request-Id: xxxxx
   X-Ms-Version: [2020-10-02]
   --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
   RESPONSE Status: 400 The specifed resource name contains invalid characters.
   Content-Length: [243]
   Content-Type: [application/xml]
   Date: [Fri, 10 Feb 2023 15:40:30 GMT]
   Server: [Windows-Azure-Blob/1.0 Microsoft-HTTPAPI/2.0]
   X-Ms-Client-Request-Id: [x]
   X-Ms-Error-Code: [InvalidResourceName]
   X-Ms-Request-Id: [x]
   X-Ms-Version: [x]
```

Answer (score 0):

Created the two Gen2 Storage Accounts with the below paths:

1. Source Storage Account:
   `harisadlsgen2src (gen2 storage account) >> hari (container name) >> 2023 >> 02 >> 10 (directories)`

- Uploaded some text files in the source Storage Account Hierarchical Path:
  [image]

2. Destination Storage Account:
   `harisadlsgen2dstn (gen2 storage account) >> test (container name)`

[image]

**Note**:

1. Container is created on the Container Access Level in both Storage accounts.
2. Generate the **SAS URL** with the permissions Read, Write, List, create in both Storage Account Containers and modify the directory path as per your requirement.
3. Open the Azure CLI or Command Prompt with the **azcopy** tool path and you have to use the double quotes and single quote in all other command shells.
4. Commands I have used:

```bash
az login --tenant <your_Azure_Tenant_Id>
az account set --subscription "<Your_Subscription_Id>"
azcopy copy "https://harisadlsgen2src.blob.core.windows.net/hari/2023/02/10?sp=<SAS_URL>" "https://harisadlsgen2dstn.blob.core.windows.net/test?sp=<SAS_URL>" --recursive
```

[image]

[image]

Refer to this [MS Doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-use-azcopy-blobs-copy) for more information on Az Copy command guidelines for the Directory Contents Copy.